# Intermittent connection success to Firebird 1.5.4 using RazorSQL 9.3 and included (current) Firebird JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I'm connecting to a set of Firebird 1.5.2 servers (2.4.20 Linux kernel - circa 2003. These are a closed, end of life system serving a telephony application (Service Control Point) in an SS7 switching environment.  They will not ever be upgraded to current distributions of any components, would a monumental job from rewriting kernel drivers up through two hardware abstraction layers.  Just in case you were about to ask. Moreover, they run and run and rarely fail with due to tremendous redundancy in power, drives, processes and connectivity.  Designed for Five Nines.

We have a central syncing application that is also running 1.5.2, in-house custom connect C library, connections are fine, reliable, rock solid.

In order to assist in some service migrations (I was the original principal designer of the system 18 years ago), I need to access the databases (as well as other components); Now I had an old VM running FlameRobin, but you know, Intel VM not happy to be on an M1. So I just installed Razor 9.3 on my very new Mac M1.

It does connect to the databases, but it is a hit or miss for success.  Sometimes it gets it on the first try, other time 3 or 4 or 5 failures then bang, connect.

I recalled a colleague in our IS group mention that for a Windows Delphi app [unclear how it connects] they had to set the connection attempts into a loop (tries a max of 50 times), because it was likely to fail.  So on fail I knew to just try again, being reasonably sure of my settings.

I understand that the current JDBC driver supports  Firebird 2+, and that it works on 1.5.4 is a bonus; and humbly I ask a two fold question:

One of curiosity: why is it intermittent - I would expect the same behaviour across attempts?

One of fear: is a subsequent update to the JDBC driver likely to fix the inconsistency and make all attempts fail?

When connection fails, the error received is:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to 
the database:  

JDBC URL: 
jdbc:firebirdsql://10.X.X.X//usr/local/somepath/some.fdb 

connection rejected by remote interface [SQLState:08004, ISC 
error code:335544421]
```

On the server the firebird shows

SCP01   Wed Apr  7 11:51:33 2021
SERVER/process_packet: connect reject, server exiting

SCP01   Wed Apr  7 11:51:33 2021
SERVER/process_packet: connect reject, server exiting

tcpdump of successful connection - this trace differs from the failure at the 16 or 17th packet.  The 192. is the client, the 10. is the server.

```
09:19:19.467277 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x84b7 (correct), seq 3429195333, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1496670700 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 4006 3a5d c0a8 3472  E..@..@.@.:]..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 5e45 0000 0000  ...=.....e^E....
    0x0020:  b0c2 ffff 84b7 0000 0204 0514 0103 0306  ................
    0x0030:  0101 080a 5935 61ec 0000 0000 0402 0000  ....Y5a.........
09:19:19.492791 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1734, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49170: Flags [S.], cksum 0xeb79 (correct), seq 610193967, ack 3429195334, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1450067643 ecr 1496670700,nop,wscale 0], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 06c6 4000 3906 3a9b 0a04 013d  E..<..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c012 245e d22f cc65 5e46  ..4r....$^./.e^F
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 eb79 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .....y..........
    0x0030:  566e 46bb 5935 61ec 0103 0300            VnF.Y5a.....
09:19:19.492813 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0x28c2 (correct), seq 3429195334, ack 610193968, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670725 ecr 1450067643], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 5e46 245e d230  ...=.....e^F$^.0
    0x0020:  8010 0804 28c2 0000 0101 080a 5935 6205  ....(.......Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46bb                                VnF.
09:19:19.494984 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 528)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8aa4 (correct), seq 3429195334:3429195810, ack 610193968, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670727 ecr 1450067643], length 476
    0x0000:  4500 0210 0000 4000 4006 388d c0a8 3472  E.....@.@.8...4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 5e46 245e d230  ...=.....e^F$^.0
    0x0020:  8018 0804 8aa4 0000 0101 080a 5935 6207  ............Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46bb 0000 0001 0000 0013 0000 0003  VnF.............
    0x0040:  0000 0001 0000 0020 2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63  ......../usr/loc
    <snip>
        0x01a0:  0419 4461 6e69 656c 732d 4d61 6342 6f6f  ..Daniels-MacBoo
    0x01b0:  6b2d 4169 722e 6c6f 6361 6c06 0020 2020  k-Air.local.....
    0x01c0:  0000 000a 0000 0001 0000 0002 0000 0003  ................
    0x01d0:  0000 0001 0000 800b 0000 0001 0000 0005  ................
    0x01e0:  0000 0005 0000 0002 0000 800c 0000 0001  ................
    0x01f0:  0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0003 0000 800d  ................
    0x0200:  0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0004  ................
09:19:19.520781 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1735, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49170: Flags [.], cksum 0x15c5 (correct), seq 610193968, ack 3429195810, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067646 ecr 1496670727], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 06c7 4000 3906 3aa2 0a04 013d  E..4..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c012 245e d230 cc65 6022  ..4r....$^.0.e`"
    0x0020:  8010 1920 15c5 0000 0101 080a 566e 46be  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 6207                                Y5b.
09:19:19.536740 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1753, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49170: Flags [P.], cksum 0x15b3 (correct), seq 610193968:610193972, ack 3429195810, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067648 ecr 1496670727], length 4
    0x0000:  4500 0038 06d9 4000 3906 3a8c 0a04 013d  E..8..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c012 245e d230 cc65 6022  ..4r....$^.0.e`"
    0x0020:  8018 1920 15b3 0000 0101 080a 566e 46c0  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 6207 0000 0004                      Y5b.....
09:19:19.536752 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0x26b3 (correct), seq 3429195810, ack 610193972, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670767 ecr 1450067648], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 6022 245e d234  ...=.....e`"$^.4
    0x0020:  8010 0804 26b3 0000 0101 080a 5935 622f  ....&.......Y5b/
    0x0030:  566e 46c0                                VnF.
09:19:19.536762 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1754, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49170: Flags [F.], cksum 0x15be (correct), seq 610193972, ack 3429195810, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067648 ecr 1496670727], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 06da 4000 3906 3a8f 0a04 013d  E..4..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c012 245e d234 cc65 6022  ..4r....$^.4.e`"
    0x0020:  8011 1920 15be 0000 0101 080a 566e 46c0  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 6207                                Y5b.
09:19:19.536770 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0x26b2 (correct), seq 3429195810, ack 610193973, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670767 ecr 1450067648], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 6022 245e d235  ...=.....e`"$^.5
    0x0020:  8010 0804 26b2 0000 0101 080a 5935 622f  ....&.......Y5b/
    0x0030:  566e 46c0                                VnF.
09:19:19.536816 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49170 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [F.], cksum 0x26b1 (correct), seq 3429195810, ack 610193973, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670767 ecr 1450067648], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c012 0bea cc65 6022 245e d235  ...=.....e`"$^.5
    0x0020:  8011 0804 26b1 0000 0101 080a 5935 622f  ....&.......Y5b/
    0x0030:  566e 46c0                                VnF.
09:19:19.553654 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x7202 (correct), seq 116864533, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1496670783 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 4006 3a5d c0a8 3472  E..@..@.@.:]..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3615 0000 0000  ...=......6.....
    0x0020:  b0c2 ffff 7202 0000 0204 0514 0103 0306  ....r...........
    0x0030:  0101 080a 5935 623f 0000 0000 0402 0000  ....Y5b?........
09:19:19.559660 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1755, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49170: Flags [.], cksum 0x1593 (correct), seq 610193973, ack 3429195811, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067650 ecr 1496670767], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 06db 4000 3906 3a8e 0a04 013d  E..4..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c012 245e d235 cc65 6023  ..4r....$^.5.e`#
    0x0020:  8010 1920 1593 0000 0101 080a 566e 46c2  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 622f                                Y5b/
09:19:19.591334 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1756, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49171: Flags [S.], cksum 0x7b97 (correct), seq 614280980, ack 116864534, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1450067653 ecr 1496670783,nop,wscale 0], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 06dc 4000 3906 3a85 0a04 013d  E..<..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c013 249d 2f14 06f7 3616  ..4r....$./...6.
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 7b97 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ....{...........
    0x0030:  566e 46c5 5935 623f 0103 0300            VnF.Y5b?....
09:19:19.591352 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xb8d3 (correct), seq 116864534, ack 614280981, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670820 ecr 1450067653], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3616 249d 2f15  ...=......6.$./.
    0x0020:  8010 0804 b8d3 0000 0101 080a 5935 6264  ............Y5bd
    0x0030:  566e 46c5                                VnF.
09:19:19.592148 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 532)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0x326f (correct), seq 116864534:116865014, ack 614280981, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670820 ecr 1450067653], length 480
    0x0000:  4500 0214 0000 4000 4006 3889 c0a8 3472  E.....@.@.8...4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3616 249d 2f15  ...=......6.$./.
    0x0020:  8018 0804 326f 0000 0101 080a 5935 6264  ....2o......Y5bd
    0x0030:  566e 46c5 0000 0001 0000 0013 0000 0003  VnF.............
    0x0040:  0000 0001 0000 0021 2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63  .......!/usr/loc
        <snip>
    0x01a0:  6e69 656c 0419 4461 6e69 656c 732d 4d61  niel..Daniels-Ma
    0x01b0:  6342 6f6f 6b2d 4169 722e 6c6f 6361 6c06  cBook-Air.local.
    0x01c0:  0020 2020 0000 000a 0000 0001 0000 0002  ................
    0x01d0:  0000 0003 0000 0001 0000 800b 0000 0001  ................
    0x01e0:  0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0002 0000 800c  ................
    0x01f0:  0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0003  ................
    0x0200:  0000 800d 0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005  ................
    0x0210:  0000 0004                                ....
09:19:19.625717 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1757, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49171: Flags [.], cksum 0xa5d3 (correct), seq 614280981, ack 116865014, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067657 ecr 1496670820], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 06dd 4000 3906 3a8c 0a04 013d  E..4..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c013 249d 2f15 06f7 37f6  ..4r....$./...7.
    0x0020:  8010 1920 a5d3 0000 0101 080a 566e 46c9  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 6264                                Y5bd
09:19:19.633936 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1746, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 68)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49171: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa5a9 (correct), seq 614280981:614280997, ack 116865014, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067658 ecr 1496670820], length 16
    0x0000:  4500 0044 06d2 4000 3906 3a87 0a04 013d  E..D..@.9.:....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c013 249d 2f15 06f7 37f6  ..4r....$./...7.
    0x0020:  8018 1920 a5a9 0000 0101 080a 566e 46ca  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 6264 0000 0003 0000 000a 0000 0001  Y5bd............
    0x0040:  0000 0003                                ....
09:19:19.633943 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xb6b6 (correct), seq 116865014, ack 614280997, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670860 ecr 1450067658], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 37f6 249d 2f25  ...=......7.$./%
    0x0020:  8010 0804 b6b6 0000 0101 080a 5935 628c  ............Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46ca                                VnF.
09:19:19.634826 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 164)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0x6de4 (correct), seq 116865014:116865126, ack 614280997, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670860 ecr 1450067658], length 112
    0x0000:  4500 00a4 0000 4000 4006 39f9 c0a8 3472  E.....@.@.9...4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 37f6 249d 2f25  ...=......7.$./%
    0x0020:  8018 0804 6de4 0000 0101 080a 5935 628c  ....m.......Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46ca 0000 0013 0000 0000 0000 0021  VnF............!
    0x0040:  2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63 616c 2f63 6d64 4461  /usr/local/cmdDa
        <snip>
    0x0080:  7351 5932 3f04 0300 0000 3904 2300 0000  sQY2?.....9.#...
    0x0090:  5b0f 416d 6572 6963 612f 546f 726f 6e74  [.America/Toront
    0x00a0:  6f00 0000                                o...
09:19:19.703801 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1760, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49171: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa4f2 (correct), seq 614280997:614281029, ack 116865126, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067664 ecr 1496670860], length 32
    0x0000:  4500 0054 06e0 4000 3906 3a69 0a04 013d  E..T..@.9.:i...=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c013 249d 2f25 06f7 3866  ..4r....$./%..8f
    0x0020:  8018 1920 a4f2 0000 0101 080a 566e 46d0  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 628c 0000 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000  Y5b.............
    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000  ................
    0x0050:  0000 0000                                ....
09:19:19.703820 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xb5db (correct), seq 116865126, ack 614281029, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670929 ecr 1450067664], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3866 249d 2f45  ...=......8f$./E
    0x0020:  8010 0804 b5db 0000 0101 080a 5935 62d1  ............Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46d0                                VnF.
09:19:19.704234 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 80)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0x31c2 (correct), seq 116865126:116865154, ack 614281029, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670929 ecr 1450067664], length 28
    0x0000:  4500 0050 0000 4000 4006 3a4d c0a8 3472  E..P..@.@.:M..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3866 249d 2f45  ...=......8f$./E
    0x0020:  8018 0804 31c2 0000 0101 080a 5935 62d1  ....1.......Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46d0 0000 0028 0000 0000 0000 0000  VnF....(........
    0x0040:  0000 0005 3e67 2021 0120 2020 0000 0400  ....>g.!........
09:19:19.740991 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 1761, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 1108)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.49171: Flags [P.], cksum 0xc58d (correct), seq 614281029:614282085, ack 116865154, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450067668 ecr 1496670929], length 1056
    0x0000:  4500 0454 06e1 4000 3906 3668 0a04 013d  E..T..@.9.6h...=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea c013 249d 2f45 06f7 3882  ..4r....$./E..8.
    0x0020:  8018 1920 c58d 0000 0101 080a 566e 46d4  ............VnF.
    0x0030:  5935 62d1 0000 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000  Y5b.............
    0x0040:  0000 0000 0000 0400 3e01 0001 6749 0002  ........>...gI..
    0x0050:  1b4c 492d 5631 2e35 2e32 2e34 3733 3120  .LI-V1.5.2.4731.
    0x0060:  4669 7265 6269 7264 2031 2e35 2b4c 492d  Firebird.1.5+LI-
    0x0070:  5631 2e35 2e32 2e34 3733 3120 4669 7265  V1.5.2.4731.Fire
    0x0080:  6269 7264 2031 2e35 2f74 6370 2028 5343  bird.1.5/tcp.(SC
    0x0090:  5030 3129 2f50 3130 2004 000a 0000 0021  P01)/P10.......!
    0x00a0:  0400 0100 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        <snip>
    0x0440:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000  ................
    0x0450:  0000 0000                                ....
09:19:19.741007 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.49171 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xb188 (correct), seq 116865154, ack 614282085, win 2035, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496670965 ecr 1450067668], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d c013 0bea 06f7 3882 249d 3365  ...=......8.$.3e
    0x0020:  8010 07f3 b188 0000 0101 080a 5935 62f5  ............Y5b.
    0x0030:  566e 46d4                                VnF.
```

tcpdump of failed connection

```
09:18:41.315669 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [SEW], cksum 0x62cf (correct), seq 1302090607, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1496632746 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 4006 3a5d c0a8 3472  E..@..@.@.:]..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 536f 0000 0000  ...=....M.So....
    0x0020:  b0c2 ffff 62cf 0000 0204 0514 0103 0306  ....b...........
    0x0030:  0101 080a 5934 cdaa 0000 0000 0402 0000  ....Y4..........
09:18:41.347668 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65389, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65500: Flags [S.], cksum 0x0a4c (correct), seq 570729141, ack 1302090608, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1450063829 ecr 1496632746,nop,wscale 0], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c ff6d 4000 3906 41f3 0a04 013d  E..<.m@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdc 2204 a2b5 4d9c 5370  ..4r...."...M.Sp
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 0a4c 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .....L..........
    0x0030:  566e 37d5 5934 cdaa 0103 0300            Vn7.Y4......
09:18:41.347687 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0x478d (correct), seq 1302090608, ack 570729142, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496632778 ecr 1450063829], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 5370 2204 a2b6  ...=....M.Sp"...
    0x0020:  8010 0804 478d 0000 0101 080a 5934 cdca  ....G.......Y4..
    0x0030:  566e 37d5                                Vn7.
09:18:41.651317 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 528)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0x9017 (correct), seq 1302090608:1302091084, ack 570729142, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633077 ecr 1450063829], length 476
    0x0000:  4500 0210 0000 4000 4006 388d c0a8 3472  E.....@.@.8...4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 5370 2204 a2b6  ...=....M.Sp"...
    0x0020:  8018 0804 9017 0000 0101 080a 5934 cef5  ............Y4..
    0x0030:  566e 37d5 0000 0001 0000 0013 0000 0003  Vn7.............
    0x0040:  0000 0001 0000 0020 2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63  ......../usr/loc
    <snip>
        0x01a0:  0419 4461 6e69 656c 732d 4d61 6342 6f6f  ..Daniels-MacBoo
    0x01b0:  6b2d 4169 722e 6c6f 6361 6c06 0020 2020  k-Air.local.....
    0x01c0:  0000 000a 0000 0001 0000 0002 0000 0003  ................
    0x01d0:  0000 0001 0000 800b 0000 0001 0000 0005  ................
    0x01e0:  0000 0005 0000 0002 0000 800c 0000 0001  ................
    0x01f0:  0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0003 0000 800d  ................
    0x0200:  0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0004  ................
09:18:41.691197 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65390, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65500: Flags [.], cksum 0x3348 (correct), seq 570729142, ack 1302091084, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063863 ecr 1496633077], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 ff6e 4000 3906 41fa 0a04 013d  E..4.n@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdc 2204 a2b6 4d9c 554c  ..4r...."...M.UL
    0x0020:  8010 1920 3348 0000 0101 080a 566e 37f7  ....3H......Vn7.
    0x0030:  5934 cef5                                Y4..
09:18:41.700913 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65393, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65500: Flags [P.], cksum 0x3337 (correct), seq 570729142:570729146, ack 1302091084, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063864 ecr 1496633077], length 4
    0x0000:  4500 0038 ff71 4000 3906 41f3 0a04 013d  E..8.q@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdc 2204 a2b6 4d9c 554c  ..4r...."...M.UL
    0x0020:  8018 1920 3337 0000 0101 080a 566e 37f8  ....37......Vn7.
    0x0030:  5934 cef5 0000 0004                      Y4......
09:18:41.700921 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0x442f (correct), seq 1302091084, ack 570729146, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633125 ecr 1450063864], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 554c 2204 a2ba  ...=....M.UL"...
    0x0020:  8010 0804 442f 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf25  ....D/......Y4.%
    0x0030:  566e 37f8                                Vn7.
09:18:41.701042 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [F.], cksum 0x442e (correct), seq 1302091084, ack 570729146, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633125 ecr 1450063864], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 554c 2204 a2ba  ...=....M.UL"...
    0x0020:  8011 0804 442e 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf25  ....D.......Y4.%
    0x0030:  566e 37f8                                Vn7.
09:18:41.701717 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65394, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65500: Flags [F.], cksum 0x3342 (correct), seq 570729146, ack 1302091084, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063864 ecr 1496633077], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 ff72 4000 3906 41f6 0a04 013d  E..4.r@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdc 2204 a2ba 4d9c 554c  ..4r...."...M.UL
    0x0020:  8011 1920 3342 0000 0101 080a 566e 37f8  ....3B......Vn7.
    0x0030:  5934 cef5                                Y4..
09:18:41.701727 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65500 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [F.], cksum 0x442d (correct), seq 1302091084, ack 570729147, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633125 ecr 1450063864], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdc 0bea 4d9c 554c 2204 a2bb  ...=....M.UL"...
    0x0020:  8011 0804 442d 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf25  ....D-......Y4.%
    0x0030:  566e 37f8                                Vn7.
09:18:41.708391 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 64)
    192.168.52.114.65501 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [SEW], cksum 0xff81 (correct), seq 179959836, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 1496633132 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 4006 3a5d c0a8 3472  E..@..@.@.:]..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdd 0bea 0ab9 f81c 0000 0000  ...=............
    0x0020:  b0c2 ffff ff81 0000 0204 0514 0103 0306  ................
    0x0030:  0101 080a 5934 cf2c 0000 0000 0402 0000  ....Y4.,........
09:18:41.734738 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65391, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65500: Flags [.], cksum 0x330d (correct), seq 570729147, ack 1302091085, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063868 ecr 1496633125], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 ff6f 4000 3906 41f9 0a04 013d  E..4.o@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdc 2204 a2bb 4d9c 554d  ..4r...."...M.UM
    0x0020:  8010 1920 330d 0000 0101 080a 566e 37fc  ....3.......Vn7.
    0x0030:  5934 cf25                                Y4.%
09:18:41.735602 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65396, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65501: Flags [S.], cksum 0x6855 (correct), seq 578216133, ack 179959837, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1450063868 ecr 1496633132,nop,wscale 0], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c ff74 4000 3906 41ec 0a04 013d  E..<.t@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdd 2276 e0c5 0ab9 f81d  ..4r...."v......
    0x0020:  a012 16a0 6855 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  ....hU..........
    0x0030:  566e 37fc 5934 cf2c 0103 0300            Vn7.Y4.,....
09:18:41.735620 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65501 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xa59c (correct), seq 179959837, ack 578216134, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633158 ecr 1450063868], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdd 0bea 0ab9 f81d 2276 e0c6  ...=........"v..
    0x0020:  8010 0804 a59c 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf46  ............Y4.F
    0x0030:  566e 37fc                                Vn7.
09:18:41.736482 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 532)
    192.168.52.114.65501 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [P.], cksum 0xb417 (correct), seq 179959837:179960317, ack 578216134, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633158 ecr 1450063868], length 480
    0x0000:  4500 0214 0000 4000 4006 3889 c0a8 3472  E.....@.@.8...4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdd 0bea 0ab9 f81d 2276 e0c6  ...=........"v..
    0x0020:  8018 0804 b417 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf46  ............Y4.F
    0x0030:  566e 37fc 0000 0001 0000 0013 0000 0003  Vn7.............
    0x0040:  0000 0001 0000 0021 2f75 7372 2f6c 6f63  .......!/usr/loc
    <snip>
        0x01a0:  6e69 656c 0419 4461 6e69 656c 732d 4d61  niel..Daniels-Ma
    0x01b0:  6342 6f6f 6b2d 4169 722e 6c6f 6361 6c06  cBook-Air.local.
    0x01c0:  0020 2020 0000 000a 0000 0001 0000 0002  ................
    0x01d0:  0000 0003 0000 0001 0000 800b 0000 0001  ................
    0x01e0:  0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0002 0000 800c  ................
    0x01f0:  0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005 0000 0003  ................
    0x0200:  0000 800d 0000 0001 0000 0005 0000 0005  ................
    0x0210:  0000 0004                                ....
09:18:41.758811 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65397, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65501: Flags [.], cksum 0x929e (correct), seq 578216134, ack 179960317, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063870 ecr 1496633158], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 ff75 4000 3906 41f3 0a04 013d  E..4.u@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdd 2276 e0c6 0ab9 f9fd  ..4r...."v......
    0x0020:  8010 1920 929e 0000 0101 080a 566e 37fe  ............Vn7.
    0x0030:  5934 cf46                                Y4.F
09:18:41.773914 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 65399, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 56)
    10.4.1.61.3050 > 192.168.52.114.65501: Flags [P.], cksum 0x928c (correct), seq 578216134:578216138, ack 179960317, win 6432, options [nop,nop,TS val 1450063872 ecr 1496633158], length 4
    0x0000:  4500 0038 ff77 4000 3906 41ed 0a04 013d  E..8.w@.9.A....=
    0x0010:  c0a8 3472 0bea ffdd 2276 e0c6 0ab9 f9fd  ..4r...."v......
    0x0020:  8018 1920 928c 0000 0101 080a 566e 3800  ............Vn8.
    0x0030:  5934 cf46 0000 0004                      Y4.F....
09:18:41.773923 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65501 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [.], cksum 0xa38f (correct), seq 179960317, ack 578216138, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633195 ecr 1450063872], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdd 0bea 0ab9 f9fd 2276 e0ca  ...=........"v..
    0x0020:  8010 0804 a38f 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf6b  ............Y4.k
    0x0030:  566e 3800                                Vn8.
09:18:41.774002 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.52.114.65501 > 10.4.1.61.3050: Flags [F.], cksum 0xa38e (correct), seq 179960317, ack 578216138, win 2052, options [nop,nop,TS val 1496633195 ecr 1450063872], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0034 0000 4000 4006 3a69 c0a8 3472  E..4..@.@.:i..4r
    0x0010:  0a04 013d ffdd 0bea 0ab9 f9fd 2276 e0ca  ...=........"v..
    0x0020:  8011 0804 a38e 0000 0101 080a 5934 cf6b  ............Y4.k
    0x0030:  566e 3800                                Vn8.
<last 3 packets skipped, but out of room here, but they were somewhat repeats of prior>
```

Comment: Your Delphi applications are unlikely to use a JDBC driver, because that would be a rather odd solution (calling Java from Delphi to use the JDBC driver, while there are perfectly suitable solutions in Delphi to connect to Firebird natively). In any case, there is not really much to go on in your question to arrive at a conclusion as to the problem. You also do not explicitly specify which version of Jaybird you're using.  Could you please provide: a stacktrace of the exception, the exact version of Jaybird and if there is anything in firebird.log of the server?

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will be able to get some additional information in the early afternoon.

Comment: The Jaybird jar file is installed as part of RazorSQL and is located at /Applications/RazorSQL.app/Contents/Java/drivers/firebird.  

I grepped for the version and found 4.0.0-beta-1.

> strings jaybird.jar|grep META|grep -i version
META-INF/LICENSE.txtCOMMON DEVELOPMENT AND DISTRIBUTION LICENSE (CDDL) Version 1.0
META-INF/MANIFEST.MFManifest-Version: 1.0
META-INF/maven/org.firebirdsql.jdbc/jaybird-jdk18/pom.propertiesversion=4.0.0-beta-1
META-INF/services/org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.ProtocolDescriptororg.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.Version10Descriptor

Comment: I'll need to try and get a stack trace or perhaps a tcpdump of the rather short conversation.

Comment: Though I don't recall fixing any issues that might cause this, I suggest that you switch to a non-beta version of Jaybird, e.g. 4.0.3, 3.0.11 or 2.2.15.

Comment: Can you name a device? just of mere interest about learning a high-load high-availability device using Firebird

Comment: `Windows Delphi app also using the JDBC driver` - i don't believe it. Delphi has PLENTY of native Interbase/Firebird access libraries, and it also is native/unmanaged code, rather than a VM. PAssing Delphi data through JVM/.NET VM/Pyhton VM/PHP VM and any other VM is possible, but is very complex and absolutely unneeded. I frankly do not think what you've been told is true. I think people just don't know about internals of the system and repeat gossips which passed hand to hand through 18 years of people being hired and fired.

Comment: there was an old thread (in Russian) about FB 1.5.0 on Linux - https://www.sql.ru/forum/84857/firebird-on-linux-connection-refused - and it mentioned many things, like Linux semaphores, Linux xinet.d limits, and Firebird limits too. All in all, you have to pull out Linux logs and Firebird logs from that system and search for specific errors in those logs. I also suggest you to monitor total ammont of TCP connections to Firebird on that device, it seeems to hitting some max connections limit, so then all your applications are racing for "Max-1" situations.

Comment: I also wonder if Firebird there is SuperServer or Classic...  https://www.firebirdsql.org/pdfmanual/html/qsg15-classic-or-super.html

Comment: "Sometimes it gets it on the first try, other time 3 or 4 or 5 failures then bang, connect." - "Max minus one" - someone got diconnected and you was lucky to steal the freed slot before any other application did. Race conditions for limited resource. // All in all this questions would be very deep and rather wide investigation of old Linux environment (both kernel and userspace) and old Firebird too. StackOVerflow and other Q&A sites are set for narrow and shallow questions, but lots of. I believe you better go into FB-general or FB-support with it. https://firebirdsql.org/en/mailing-lists/

Comment: Thanks for the comments Arioch.  I may have been mistaken about what the colleague stated regarding the Delphi app so I removed the JDBC reference from my question.  Classic Server.  No, not a max connection thing.  At the time there were 4 connections to the server.  Mine became number 5.  I could also add more.  The high availability is through the design.  On each of the SCPs there is an A and B database.  They are always the same, kept in sync by central updating process that connects to all SCPs.  There are multiple SCPs with redundant SS7 connections to the peer in the network.

Comment: Also updated the question as to the firebird version.  I thought it was 1.5.4, but it's 1.5.2, it's been almost 20 years so my memory is foggy.   Holy crap!  I just read that again, I am asking about intermittent failures on a connectivity issue between current and 20 year old software.

Comment: Updated to 4.0.3 for Java 11. Same behaviour. Added a tcp dump capture for success and for failure into the question

Comment: The thing is, Firebird 1.5.2 (and other 1.5.x versions) have several issues related to connection crashes and even server crashes on connect. It is possible that some of the modifications for supporting the Firebird 3+ protocol is causing Firebird to choke. I'd recommend that you try with Jaybird 2.2.15 (which doesn't include the protocol improvements introduced in Jaybird 3.0). I'll try to see if I see anything in the tcpdump, but decoding the Firebird protocol is not my favourite hobby...

Comment: I do not believe in `connectivity issue between current and 20 year old software` here yet, You said ancient Delphi app stuggles the same as your new shiny Java/Jaybird app., so i still think there is non-stop banging ones' heads against some bottleneck in max-limited connection numbers, and you would have to either blindly join the races and do not give a flying thought about how it still works, or to investigate it from the insides of the sever, starting with all the logs there, which would need experience with 20 y.o. Linux kernel and userland environments too, not only with old Firebird.

Comment: It does not has to be limit in Firebird code, it can be limit in Linux kernel arrays that gets projected through Firebird. Read the link i posted above. `SERVER/process_packet: connect reject` sounds consistent to me - Linux denied some resource to Firebird and it properly died off. And even while you are focused on network - why manually parse hex blobs? https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/g/gdsdb.html and https://www.firebirdnews.org/wireshark-firebird-dissector-call-for-contributors/

Comment: You may want to look at your inetd/xinetd config, maybe the connections per second setting is very low, or there is a very low max connection setting.